# What is the Conventional Notation for Polynomial Exponentiation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem that involves polynomial exponentiation, e.g.

$$
P(x) = \left (
\sum_{k=0}^N a_k x^k 
\right)^M ~~|~~ N, M \in \mathbb{Z} \ge 0 
$$

For what I'm doing, it's much easier to deal with the coefficient vector, $a$:

$$
a \overset{\Delta}=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a_0 \\ a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_N
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Now I know that polynomial multiplication would be equivalent to the linear convolution ($\ast$) of the coefficient vector, so I can represent this as a vector product

$$
P(x) = 
\left(
a \ast a \ast ... \text{convolve M - 1 times}... \ast a 
\right)
\circ \left (
\begin{matrix}
x^0 \\ x^1 \\ \vdots \\ x^{N\times M}
\end{matrix}
\right )
$$

My question is: is there a well used shorthand for that repeated convolution operation? In other words, what is the convention for representing polynomial exponentiation in terms of the coefficient vector?

Currently I'm using this shorthand, but I just made it up:

$$
a^{\ast M} \overset{\Delta}= 
\left \{
\begin{matrix}
1 && M = 0 \\
a && M = 1 \\
a \ast a \ast ... \ast a && M > 1
\end{matrix}
\right . 
$$

Comment: The conventional notation for polynomial exponentiation is of course $p(x)^M$, as you have written in your first equation. For *repeated convolution*, on the other hand, it seems $a^{*M}$ is indeed not an uncommon notation, see e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/q/324793, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/506677